# Better JavaScript rounding (non-"banker's rounding")

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I would like to reduce this down to 5 decimal places.  Except, I can't simply round and get .03085, I need to look further down the number and round all the digits up so that I will get .03086.

Input: 0.030854494999999999

Undesired: 0.030854494999999999.toFixed( 5) = 0.03085

Desired output: .03086

Comment: I think you meant `.toFixed(5)`

Comment: There is no absolute way to do this due to the way [floating point math works](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). There will always be some percentage of error because of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of "looking farther down the number to round all the the digits up" does not make sense if the intent is to obtain the **closest** approximation to a value using a result with limited precision. The best approximation in this case depends only upon the *next* digit beyond the desired precision, in this example being a 4 thereby rounding down.

However, in some circumstances, the **desired** approximation is the smallest value at the required precision which is greater than the input value. An example would be cutting a hole to allow an object to be inserted. Clearly the hole must be bigger than the object to be useful. In this case, the answer by @oriol would give a correct result although, often, the precision required is known in advance and so a more specific (and so efficient) routine could be used. In particular, the use of `Math.pow()` is fairly expensive (and possibly less accurate) compared with simple multiply and divide and so should be avoided where practical, especially if many approximations are required. If the desired precision is known in advance, the routine could be simplified as follows (same name used):

```
 function myRounding(num)
 {
   // Don't need to calculate
   // var power10 = Math.pow(10, decimals);
   // just use appropriate value directly

   return Math.ceil(num * 1e5) / 1e5; // For 5 decimal places
 }

 myRounding(0.030854494999999999); // 0.03086
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
function myRounding(num, decimals) {
    var power10 = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.ceil(num*power10) / power10;
}
myRounding(0.030854494999999999, 5); // 0.03086
```

Comment: This gives me an idea.  One could use pow and Math.round (instead of ceil) to round the number many times to the desired precision.  However, you solution actually fits better to what we need.